# Where can I initialize module-wide variables?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['ui'])
    .config(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.Gender = {
            'M': 'Male',
            'F': 'Female',
            'U': 'Unknown',
        };
    })
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $rootScope from MyModule

If I can't access `$rootScope` inside my module config, where's the proper place to initialize module-wide variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't inject services (here $rootScope) into config block. Only constants and providers can be injected during the config phase.

In your case the correct solution would be to use the run block. Just change config to run and things should be working as expected.

Comment: I don't think $rootScope is a good way to make your application modular and somehow breaks the SRP rule

Answer (score 25):

Instead of using `$rootScope`, you could also use an angular constant or value:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', ['ui']).constant( 'Gender', {
  'M': 'Male',
  'F': 'Female',
  'U': 'Unknown',
});
```

A constant can never be changed, whereas a value can. And you can inject it wherever you need it:

```js
app.controller( 'MainController', function ( $scope, Gender ) {
  console.log( Gender.M );
});
```

In my opinion. this seems more "proper" for site-wide variables than using `$rootScope`.

Comment: But can I access constants in my view? I don't want to need to inject it.

Comment: @Mark It would need to be injected, yes. But I'm not sure why that's a bad thing. Polluting $rootScope, however, *is* usually a bad thing. Think of $rootScope as the global namespace of your app - things generally don't belong there.

Comment: But they're enums..they're like types. Types *are* generally available globally - or least within a namespace - which is my goal here. How do you even access a constant in a view? It doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: @Mark It doesn't sound like yours is a terrible use case or anything, but $rootScope isn't one namespace - it affects all of the namespaces within your app. Views are not supposed to contain model logic, so you can't inject services into them; services are injected into controllers, which in turn add relevant model data to the scope. You're doing the same thing here, but the difference is that $rootScope is the highest scope and all other scopes inherit from it prototypically, so it is available everywhere. Why do you need an JS enum or type in your view?

Comment: I've created a filter called `map` which I call like `{{client.gender|map:Gender}}` which translates what I have stored in my object/database to something more human-readable. Since this is a formatting thing, my understanding is that the best place for this is the view.

Comment: Mark, why don't you encapsulate gender's enum in a filter then? Is it used elsewhere? If this is just an enum I would agree with @Josh that a constant might be a better solution here.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource: Put it in the filter and reference it via string instead? I'm not keen on stringly typing, plus it *is* used elsewhere. How does everyone else handle radio menus and drop-downs? Surely you want to display something different than what you store, and you need some kind of mapping between the key and the label that will be used in both the menus and reporting, and maybe some business logic as well.

Comment: Does not explain how to initialize a 'value', only how to use it.

Comment: @Le-roy What do you mean by "initialize"?