# How can I define module-scoped variables or constants in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS modules have variables that I need to use in .config() as well as across several controllers.

Looking for a way have variables/constants attached to the module, which can be handled from config()/controller()/run() with minimum fuss. I have tried...

- Constants -- they work! However, they live in a global scope, modules step on each other, so this is not viable. I am in fact startled that constant() being global isn't documented more clearly, example code widely uses it with local (un-prefixed) variable names.
- Services -- aren't there at config() time
- $scope -- isn't there at config() time
- Inheritance -- neither JS nor Angular are rigged up for traditional inheritance, perhaps there is a way a way to set variables in a prototype that's accessible from config()...?

Ugly code example, using constants:

```
angular.module('mod.boat_groups', ["pennantapp"])
    .constant('REST_base', 'boat_groups')
    .constant('list_name', 'boat_groups')
    .constant('item_name', 'boat_group')
    .config(['$stateProvider', 'list_name', 'item_name',
        function($stateProvider, list_name, item_name) {
            'use strict';
            $stateProvider
                .state( list_name , {
                    url: '/'+list_name,
                    views: {
                        'main': {
                            templateUrl: 'app/mod/'+list_name+'/bg.tpl.html',
                            controller: 'BoatGroupsViewCtrl as ctrl'                        }
                        }
                })
                .state( item_name + '_view', {
                    url: '/'+list_name+'/:id/view',
                    views: {
                        'navbar': {
                            templateUrl: 'app/app-navbar.tpl.html'
                        },
                        'main': {
                            templateUrl: 'app/mod/'+list_name+'/bg-view.tpl.html',
                            controller: 'BoatGroupCtrl as ctrl'                     }
                        }
                })...

angular.module('mod.boat_groups')
    .controller('BoatGroupsViewCtrl', ['Restangular', 'REST_base', '$location', 'authenticationService',
        function(Restangular, REST_base, $location, authenticationService) {
            'use strict';
            var self = this;
            self.restangular = Restangular.all(REST_base)
            ...
        }]);

angular.module('mod.boat_groups')
    .controller('BoatGroupCtrl', ['Restangular', 'REST_base', 'list_name', '$location', 'authenticationService', '$stateParams',
        function(Restangular, REST_base, list_name, $location, authenticationService, $stateParams) {
            'use strict';
            var self = this;
            self.restangular = Restangular.all(REST_base)
            ...
```

Some similar questions...

- [Where is a good place for me to declare / initialize $scope variables for my module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617539/where-is-a-good-place-for-me-to-declare-initialize-scope-variables-for-my-mod)
- [Where can I initialize module-wide variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552937/where-can-i-initialize-module-wide-variables?newreg=c798ea3a9011446485cd45f1b120cacf)

Comment: Constants are global. Modules are not namespaces. Choose a unique prefix for each of your module, and prefix the constants with that prefix.

Comment: That is not very helpful. Some modules have a lot of commonality (i.e.: similar but different frontend to CRUD operations), so likely to have similarly-named variables.

This also means that modules aren't really modular :-(